# Alpine.js + laravel(inertia.js) auto hide flash messages timeout repeatedly

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

i use alpinejs to hide flash message and it works but only 1 time, how can i fix it? I understand that this is because the element is hidden after the first click, but how can I make it so that if a flash message arrives, the element reappears? I dont understand
I also have vue 3

My code for accept and hide flash message:

```
<div x-data="{ show: true }" x-show="show" x-init="setTimeout(() => show = false, 3000)" v-if="$page.props.flash.successAuth{{ $page.props.flash.successAuth}}</div>
```

For example, I make a click. flash comes, it shows up. after Alpina hides him, and that's it. repeated clicks do not work, the flash is hidden all the time.

I had an idea to remove the flash message from the DOM after a while, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Could you include a whole example? How does a flash message appear first time?

Comment: It appears in the DOM after receiving a flash from the backend, until it is received, it will not be in the DOM, and after that it remains there and it remains to hide it only through the display: none

Comment: What do you mean by 'receiving a flash from the backend'? Reloading the page or via AJAX calls? Basically you need an Alpine.js component that listens for 'flash-message' events, and you can use `$dispatch` on clicks for sending message to the component.

Comment: Through ajax, right